# Why do i have to hit Enter when i redirect the output from a WinMain to a console?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I made a simple console application, but i want to hide the console window. Therefore i removed

```
int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[ ] )
```

and added these two extra lines:

```
#pragma comment( linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS" )
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
```

Everything works fine, but i would like to have a `/?` parameter where the usage is shown. However there is no console window, i need to show it somehow. So i googled a bit, and i found this code snippet:

```
void SetStdOutToNewConsole()
{
int hConHandle;
long lStdHandle;
FILE *fp;

// allocate a console for this app
if ( !AttachConsole( ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS ) )
{
    if ( !AllocConsole( ) )
    {
         MessageBoxA( NULL, "AllocConsole failed!", NULL, NULL );
    }   
}

// redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
lStdHandle = ( long )GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
hConHandle = _open_osfhandle( lStdHandle, _O_TEXT );
fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );
*stdout = *fp;

setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

}//SetStdOutToNewConsole
```

If the `/?` is defined i call this function and i can display what i want. However if i open a cmd window, and start `myapp.exe /?` from there the text will be displayed what i want, but i have to hit an extra Enter. Why is that? Is there a way to solve this somehow, so i don't need to hit an enter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than create a console for a non-console app, why not use `MessageBox()` instead to display the help text?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: unfortunately, it is not an option for me. It is complicated, but i have to show it in a console widow.

Comment: That makes no sense. You asked: *"However there is no console window, i need to show it somehow."*, which suggests you do not care how it is displayed to the user. So `MessageBox()` would be appropriate for that. Why are you allowed to create a new popup console to display a text message for a non-console process, but you are not allowed to use `MessageBox()` to display a popup dialog to display a text message? What are you actually using the console for other than text display? It is not uncommon for a GUI app to display a popup GUI when started with a `/?` command line, even from a console.